# Django mixin not working as expected

Tags: python, django

I want to **prevent** `logged-in` users to access login and register forms.
I've build custom mixin, but it isn't working. The problem is that even if the user is logged in, he can access login and register forms instead of beeing redirected to homepage.

My Mixin

```
class MustBeAnonymousMixin(object):
    ''' Only anonymous users (not logged in) may access login and register
    '''

    def dispath(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.request.user.is_anonymous:
            return redirect(reverse('homepage'))
        return super(MustBeAnonymousMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

LoginFormView

```
class LoginFormView(MustBeAnonymousMixin, TemplateView):
    '''
    Display basic user login form
    '''
    template_name = 'members/login.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LoginFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['login_form'] = UserLoginForm()
        return context
```

I'm using Django 1.8. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the typo in `dispath` and use `is_authenticated()` instead of `is_anonymous` (as indicated in the previous answer already)

Answer (score 3):

*For another case where mixin does not work:*

**Remember:** "Mixin param" must stand before "GenericView param"

*Correct:*

```
class PostDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DeleteView):
```

*Incorrect:*

```
class PostDelete(generic.DeleteView, LoginRequiredMixin):
```

Answer (score 1):

is_anonymous should be a function call, and you probably should not use it:

> is_anonymous()
>
> Always returns False. This is a way of differentiating User and 
>   AnonymousUser objects. Generally, you should prefer using is_authenticated() to this method.